# Allow the API to accept min/max for fields other than the one sorted by

Tags: feature-request, api

Today I discovered that the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/) only honors a min/max parameter for the field that you're ordering by.
However, there are cases where you want the results where `x` is at least/most `z` ordered by `y` -- especially when trying to step through multiple pages of results.

Some examples; one may:

1. Want the 100 newest (i.e. `sort=creation_date`) users with at least 5000 reputation.
2. Or, the 5 oldest (i.e. `sort=creation_date`) questions with a score lower than 5.

This could be achieved relatively easily by adding an optional `where` argument to the API that specifies which field the value of `min` and/or `max` should be used for. If omitted the `where` argument could still default to the value of `sort`.

For a more detailed view on why someone would want this, you can check out [my question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269945/order-stackexchange-api-reponse-by-date-and-specify-minimum-votes) about how to get comments ordered by `creation_date` with a minimum score.

By now, after some more looking around, I am fairly certain that it's not possible; ergo this feature request.

---

<sup>PS: I've moved this question here from SO Meta.</sup>

Comment: Or at least when sorting by date fields.  Otherwise pagination becomes even more problematic.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles: Agreed. You may've noticed that both of my examples use `sort=creation_date`.